# Abort accessing success callback in backbone model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone model which consist of following parse method.

```
parse: function(response, options){

    // Handling Error for http response 200
    if( response.Reasons && response.Reasons[0] ){
        var errorResponse = {
            responseJSON: {
                reasons: [
                    {
                        code: response.Reasons[0].ReasonCode,
                        reason: ''
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
        options.error( errorResponse );                                                
        return errorResponse;
    }
}
```

My issue is, my web service won't give http response 500 for errors. I need to check it from the response & decide that. But the problem is, above code runs the error callback but after that it goes to the success callback as well. I need to stop that.

I receive a json response from the server, similar as following

```
{Data: {some data}}
```

for error

```
{Data: {}, Reasons: [{error code}]}
```

Please let me know how can i do that. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the response (body) in the error case? Post an example

Comment: for success: {Data: {some data}} for error: {Data: {}, Reasons: [{error code}]}

Comment: Post in the question, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone by default expects the response to be `JSON`, so if `JSON` is returned from the server the success callback is triggered. With out overriding the fetch method of backbone, you can't stop from triggering success.

Comment: The thing is, I have a base model class & all the other models extend this base model. that's why i was changing the base model's parse method so that i don't have to change the fetch, save or other methods. What are my options now?

Comment: You can't stop from parse :( , but as simple send plain text when there is an error as it is not json by default error is triggered but not success

Comment: Not allowed to change the server response. I was trying to manage this from a common place. If there none, i have to do it the hard way.

Comment: overwriting sync seems the only solution then

Comment: Thanks man, looks like sync is right place to solve my problem